# How to add a conditions in V-select?

Tags: vue.js

hi every one  i want to filter  my property like  min. bedroom and max bedroom

here i have two listbox one is minimum bedroom listbox and another one is maximum bedroom listbox

if i select 3 from minimum bedroom  as well as  5 from maximum bedroom list  this time i want to filter only 3 - 5 range  bedrooms properties

```js
export default {
data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
      minbed: "",
      maxbed: "",
    };
  },
  selectOptionsBedroom() {
    return _.uniqBy(this.blogs.map(g => g.Bedrooms));   
  }
};
```

```html
 <v-select
                            :items="blogs"
                            v-model="minbed"
                            :options=" selectOptionsBedroom"
                            label="Bedrooms"
                            item-value="Bedrooms"
                            placeholder="Min.Bed"
                          ></v-select>
```

How to create a condition here?

Comment: minimum and maximum exactly for what?

Comment: minmum bedroom and maximum bed room  https://snag.gy/5AXZqV.jpg

Comment: it's answered sooner if you more clarify you question :)

Comment: i updated the description can you check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter` with a computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
      minbed: 0,
      maxbed: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    min: {
      get() {
        return this.minbed
      },
      set(value) {
        this.minbed = value
      }
    },
    max: {
      get() {
        return this.minbed >= this.maxbed ? parseInt(this.minbed, 10) + 1 : this.maxbed
      },
      set(value) {
        this.maxbed = this.minbed >= value ? parseInt(value, 10) + 1 : value
      }
    },
    selectOptionsBedroom() {
      return !!this.blogs.length ? this.blogs.filter(g => {
        return (g.Bedrooms >= this.min) && (g.Bedrooms <= this.max)
      }) : []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.blogs = Array.from(Array(20), (x, i) => {
      return {
        Name: `Blog ${i + 1}`,
        Bedrooms: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
      }
    })
    
    this.minbed = 0
    this.maxbed = this.blogs.reduce((max, blog) => {
      return (blog.Bedrooms > max) ? blog.Bedrooms : max
    }, 0)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>Min</label>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="0" v-model="min">
  <label>Max</label>
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" v-model="max">
  <ul v-if="selectOptionsBedroom.length">
    <li v-for="item in selectOptionsBedroom" :key="item.Name">{{ item.Name }} - {{ item.Bedrooms }} {{ item.Bedrooms > 1 ? 'rooms' : 'room' }}</li>
  </ul>
  <p v-else-if="!!minbed && !!maxbed">No Results</p>
  <p v-else>Search for blogs</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks you but  above code its dosnt work i changed this code like  ' .filter(blog => blog.Bedrooms >= this.minbed ) ' its working for minimum 

if i using maximum filter code that time its dosnt work ; i think one filter at the time ; how can i fix this 

for maximim  '.filter(blog => blog.Bedrooms <= this.maxbed )"

Comment: It just needs some parentheses wrapping the comparisons. The filter callback can contain any kind of logic provided it returns a boolean value. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: its working but the page loading time only showing zero bedrooms Properties - loading time i want see all properties - i try to changed  minbed value but its not working that much

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: its working in here - 
i have one field  like 'ST' Its mean STUDIO Apartment  how to filter this one 
'"Bedrooms": "ST",'

Comment: how to add place holder  i try it this one ' placeholder="Quantity" ' its not working